# Measuring Point Density in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: statistics

Suppose we are given a non-empty set of two or more points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $P$, and we would like to quantify how *dense* those points are to one another. Let $\mathcal{D}(P)$ represent the density of the set where $0$ is not dense at all and $1$ is very dense.

Is there some sort of metric for determining $\mathcal{D}(P)$?

Comment: Average/minimum/maximum distance between points? Divided by the area of the convex hull of those I guess, but that's not a local density metric.

Comment: Do you mean density in topological sense? Are we talking about points in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes, in a topological sense. In specific, my analysis is focused on points in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $P$ is contained a known region, then one possible metric of density is to measure how much area the points in $P$ cover compared to the total region, which can be computed as the ratio of the area of the convex hull to the area of the region.

Of course, this has the disadvantage of creating immense bias in cases where there are outliers in $P$. What I mean by that is if most points are dense in $P$ and then there is a single point far away from the dense region, the density will be underestimated (reflecting that $P$ is less dense than it actually is). This is the case because, *by definition*, the convex hull is the smallest convex polygon which contains *all* points. Whether this is a problem however, really just depends on the values of $P$. If you remove outliers from $P$ before computing the density, this really becomes a non-issue. Though, it can be hard to quantify outliers.

Comment: Thanks. that's an interesting method that I didn't think of. How might I compute the area of the convex hull though? I want to use this metric because I think it will fit my data well (since my data is without outliers).